# JS - How to execute code at specific page

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to execute this js code only at page: "header-26.php" using js only.

```
if (document.createElement &&
(meta = document.createElement('meta'))) {
meta.name = "xxx";
meta.content = "xxx";
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(meta);
}
```

How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In header-26.php

echo the javascript code:

```
echo '<script>
      if (document.createElement &&
         (meta = document.createElement('meta'))) {
         meta.name = "xxx";
         meta.content = "xxx";
         document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(meta);
       }
      </script>';
```

Comment: I would like to not insert anything in the header-page. Prefer - the code to be inserted or echo only when the specific page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (window.location.pathname == 'header-26.php') {
  if (document.createElement &&
  (meta = document.createElement('meta'))) {
  meta.name = "xxx";
  meta.content = "xxx";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(meta);
  }
 }
```